# libgdx box2d drawarc

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, draw

I'm new to Libgdx and box2d. I needed to draw arc. I searched for a function finally I came up like below

```
public void drawarc (float centerx, float centery,float radius, float anglefrom, float anglediff, int steps)
{
    EdgeShape ps = new EdgeShape();

    FixtureDef psfd = new FixtureDef();
    psfd.shape = ps;

    BodyDef psbd = new BodyDef();
    psbd.allowSleep = true;
    psbd.awake = true;
    psbd.position.set(centerx, centery);
    psbd.gravityScale = 0;

    Vector2[] vertices = new Vector2[steps];

    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        double angle=Math.toRadians(anglefrom+anglediff/steps*i);
        Vector2 sc = new Vector2((float)(radius * Math.cos(angle)), 
                (float)(radius * Math.sin(angle)));
        vertices[i] = sc;
    }

    Body psd = world.createBody(psbd);

    for (int i = 1; i < steps; i++) {
        ps.set(vertices[i-1], vertices[i]);
        psd.createFixture(psfd);
    }
}
```

Its working properly but I'm not sure if its the correct way or not. Would you please check and tell me if its the efficient/correct way or not?

Thanks

Comment: The nice property of graphical output is if it "looks" right, it is right!  So congrats, it works.  That said, this isn't really a question suited to Stack Overflow (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).  You might have better luck at the Code Review stack exchange (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are drawing using box2d's debug render. It may work, but is generally not a good approach. You can keep your arc-vertex creating code, but render it differently. Look into `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.polyline` method. This is also not the best solution, but is quite easy and way more efficient than your method, because you are creating a new physical body, when you don't need one.

Note that you shouldn't use debug draw for game rendering, since it is *debug* draw and not very fast. Proper way would probably be using the `Mesh` class.